# Tabela de log utilizando MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, table, log

Como criar uma tabela de *log* de auditoria em MySQL que armazene quando e o que foi alterado em cada registro? O MySQL disponibiliza algo que pode facilitar esse tipo de coisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O MySQL não disponibiliza nada assim, até porque não é função dele dar soluções prontas para problemas específicos. Você terá que criar uma estrutura que atenda todas suas necessidade de *log* e fazer as atualizações na tabela de forma tradicional. As entradas do *log* são dados como quaisquer outros, não tem nada de especial nele.

Nem vou me arriscar dar um modelo pronto porque eu não sei o que você precisa.

Alguns irão dizer para usar uma tabela MyISAM por ser mais simples e rápida. Outros dirão para usar InnoDB por permitir melhor escalabilidade. Só você testando sua situação é que saberá qual é mais adequado. *Tunar* este DB é mais importante.

O que eu posso te ajudar é te mostrar o [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) que pode garantir a sempre escrever nesta tabela quando fizer alguma alteração em outras tabelas. Como o próprio nome indica com ele você cria os gatilhos em tabelas, então qualquer operação que foi engatilhada gerará uma outra *query* que atualizará a tabela de *log*.

Outra coisa que pode te interessar é a implementação de *temporal tables*. Veja como simular no MySQL em [resposta no DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13904/41) e [no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779230/221800).

```
CREATE TABLE `data_tracking` (
`tracking_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`data_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`field` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`old_value` INT NOT NULL ,
`new_value` INT NOT NULL ,
`modified` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Para atualizá-la faria isto (dá para generalizar e usar para qualquer tabela):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER `update_data `$$

CREATE TRIGGER `update_data` AFTER UPDATE on `data_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.field1 != OLD.field1) THEN
        INSERT INTO data_tracking 
            (`data_id` , `field` , `old_value` , `new_value` , `modified` ) 
        VALUES 
            (NEW.data_id, "field1", OLD.field1, NEW.field1, NOW());
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.field2 != OLD.field2) THEN
        INSERT INTO data_tracking 
            (`data_id` , `field` , `old_value` , `new_value` , `modified` ) 
        VALUES 
            (NEW.data_id, "field2", OLD.field2, NEW.field2, NOW());
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.field3 != OLD.field3) THEN
        INSERT INTO data_tracking 
            (`data_id` , `field` , `old_value` , `new_value` , `modified` ) 
        VALUES 
            (NEW.data_id, "field3", OLD.field3, NEW.field3, NOW());
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Trigger3.sql).

Dependendo do que quer, não é um sistema de *log* que precisa.

Talvez a solução mais adequada provavelmente é usar um sistema de *log* disponível em alguma biblioteca para sua linguagem e ela se encarregará de montar ou documentar como fazer sua tabela no MySQL. Montar a tabela no banco de dados é o menor dos problemas para cuidar em um sistema de *log*.

Comment: essa trigger é disparada automaticamente pelo SGDB quando ocorre um CRUD? não estou conseguindo criar ela no MySQL, poderia dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção a isso que conheci recentemente, é um auditor, existe um componente de auditoria provido pelo MySQL, o **[MySQL Audit Enterprise](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/audit.html)**, e existe também o **[MariaDB Audit Plugin](https://mariadb.com/blog/activating-auditing-mariadb-and-mysql-5-minutes)**, do MariaDB, que é um auditor, que gera diversos logs que podem ser bastante interessantes, para a auditoria das ações dos usuários na base de dados.

Abaixo um exemplo de arquivo de log gerado pelo MariaDB Audit em MySQL.

```
20150831 14:56:48,NoteCelso,root,localhost,326,7,QUERY,,'SET GLOBAL server_audit_logging=ON',0
20150831 14:56:51,NoteCelso,root,localhost,326,0,DISCONNECT,,,0
20150831 14:56:54,NoteCelso,root,localhost,327,0,FAILED_CONNECT,,,1045
20150831 14:56:54,NoteCelso,root,localhost,327,0,DISCONNECT,,,0
20150831 14:56:57,NoteCelso,root,localhost,328,0,CONNECT,,,0
20150831 14:56:57,NoteCelso,root,localhost,328,10,QUERY,,'select @@version_comment limit 1',0
20150831 14:57:02,NoteCelso,root,localhost,328,11,QUERY,,'show databases',0
20150831 14:57:38,NoteCelso,root,localhost,328,0,DISCONNECT,,,0
20150831 14:58:05,NoteCelso,root,localhost,230,12,QUERY,,'select * from extratos LIMIT 0, 1000',0
20150831 16:46:03,NoteCelso,root,localhost,406,439,QUERY,,'SET NAMES \'utf8\'',0
20150831 16:46:03,NoteCelso,root,localhost,406,440,QUERY,,'SET character_set_connection=utf8',0
20150831 16:46:03,NoteCelso,root,localhost,406,441,QUERY,,'SET character_set_client=utf8',0
20150831 16:46:03,NoteCelso,root,localhost,406,442,QUERY,,'SET character_set_results=utf8',0
20150831 16:46:03,NoteCelso,root,localhost,406,443,QUERY,,'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS idVendedor, nome, saldo_verba, saldo_verba_pendente
        FROM   vendedores

        ORDER BY  idVendedor
                    asc
        LIMIT 0, 9',0
20150831 16:46:03,NoteCelso,root,localhost,406,444,QUERY,,'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()',0
20150831 16:46:03,NoteCelso,root,localhost,406,445,QUERY,,'SELECT COUNT(idVendedor)
        FROM   vendedores',0
20150831 16:46:03,NoteCelso,root,localhost,406,0,DISCONNECT,,,0
```

Em alguns casos uma solução desta já resolve, dependendo da necessidade.